# This code is giving me error: Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function: jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5m.access

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init()
{
  var contacts = localStorage.contacts ? JSON.parse(localStorage.contacts) : [];
  var contact;
// if there is no storage yet, on click of button new person gets in.
$("#submit").on("click", addNewContact);
}

function addNewContact()
{
  // push every person in empty array by forming an object.
  contact = {
    name: $("#name").val,
    email: $("#email").val,
    phone: $("#phone").val,
    address: $("#address").val
  }
  contacts = JSON.stringify(contact);
  localStorage.contacts = contacts;
  updatePerson();
}
function updatePerson(){
  var $tr = $("<tr>")
  .append($("<td>").text(contact.name))
  .append($("<td>").text(contact.email))
  .append($("<td>").text(contact.phone))
  .append($("<td>").text(contact.address));

  $("#table").append($tr);

}
```

This code is giving me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function: Uncaught TypeError:
>   this.each is not a functionm.fn.extend.val @
>   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5m.access @
>   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4m.fn.extend.text @
>   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4updatePerson @ Contacts.js:26addNewContact @
>   Contacts.js:22m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4r.handle @
>   jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4 Navigated to file:index.html

Comment: All of your `$("#...").val` should be  `$("#...").val()`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the contact has been assigned correctly, as it is not valid in your code due to the .val instead of .val()